# Android Studio 1.1cannot resolve symbol R

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have been stuck on this for the past week. I have combed through numerous SO posts about this, but still no luck. I have done a project clean, removed any .R imports, and a gradlew clean, as well. I'm sure there have been other attempts as well, but those are the first that came to mind.

Please, please help me, and end my torture!

Oh yeah, I have just downloaded the newest Android Studio and I have imported my project from Eclipse. The ultimate goal is to get what I have to compile so that I can add Android Wear capabilities to my app.

Thanks

Comment: Give the code where you are trying to use r

Comment: Give your XML files, that is 90% of all R-related problems

Comment: Well the entire project is covered in R, so to speak, but here is one example:

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);setContentView(R.layout.chart_layout);

Comment: I'm new to Android, and I have taken over someone else's work. Which XML file are you referring to? I see a few of them.

Comment: You tend to get `unresolved variable: R` if you have an XML resource that's bugged/invalid, and so it doesn't get autogenerated.

Comment: Is there a common XML file that is the source of it, like the Manifest.xml?

Comment: @erics - unfortunately, no.

Comment: If there is any error in the XML file at all, will this affect the R error that I have been trying to solve? Because I have been also fixing issues with external libraries needing to be added to the project still, and I currently see an error with googleplay services in my XML file.